# Cannot create Facebook test user "Unsupported method, post "

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When I attempt to create a Facebook test user I get the following response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported method, post ",
      "type": "Exception"
   }
}
```

I am using the following code...

```
require_once 'config.php';//contains my $FB_APP_ID and $FB_APP_SECRET variables
require_once 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(

  'appId'  => $FB_APP_ID,

  'secret' => $FB_APP_SECRET

));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$FB_APP_ID/accounts/test-users?
installed=true
&name=JoesTestUser
&locale=en_US
&permissions=read_stream
&method=post
&access_token=$access_token";

header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Has anyone else run into this "Unsupported method, post " issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may be able to answer my own question. Instead of creating test users programmatically you can now do it via the developer dashboard UI.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question - the API should work for this, and the real question is why it's not working for you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an [**app access token**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/). Creating test users programatically could be very useful if you have to integrate it to your system and testing app.

Comment: I also wrote a [small tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/introduction-to-facebook-test-users-accounts-with-php-sdk/40/) about test users a while back that you may interest you.